# Embedded PS vs ATX PS, can they used in place of each other?

Tags: power-supply, embedded, atx

The embedded power supply in my machine has gotten damaged/weak, It is used for powering only the Embedded Computer/Controller on the Machine. The Embedded Power Supply looks something like this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLFQc.jpg

The Power Supply has outputs of 12v 8A 5V 4A -12V 1A and input of 220VAC, these are the same outputs/inputs that an ATX PSU gives, so can substitute an ATX PSU for it because they are normally much higher rated than the embedded ps and cheaper too.

I am thinking of making it start by shorting the green and black wire, and connecting it to the machine, by making appropriate connections.

Would something like this work or is there a Fundamental difference b/w the two types of power supplies?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can try it, sure. Your pictured power supply appears to have common returns so an ATX power supply may work, so long as the rise times and sequencing of outputs are OK.

If the ATX power supply is much stronger than the one you're replacing (higher current) and you have some abnormal condition like an overload or a short, the stiffer power supply may end up further damaging the load.

Many safety-approved items say "use only model X power supply" on their labels. Be careful if you see something like this.

If your end equipment does work with the ATX power supply, you at least know where the fault lies (i.e. the power supply) and may wish to either source an identical replacement or attempt a repair.